# Using Mix IDE on a private testnet?

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain, contract-debugging, mix

Is it possible to run/debug contracts in mix-ide on a private test net?

Comment: Mix has been discontinued https://github.com/ethereum/mix/issues/327#issuecomment-232865580

Comment: So what's the next best thing? if any?

Comment: There is a new debugger called Remix in process, but it's not in a point where it could do source code level debugging. So for now your best bet is to use Mix with its current limitations I would say.

Comment: What are the most relevant limitations? Up to this point I'm having some trouble with searching for data in large arrays.

Comment: Doesn't run on private testnet? :)

Comment: When I launched it, it started mining on Frontier.